How to configure VMware to not use host display scaling?
I have VMware Workstation 17 installed on Linux using Wayland and Gnome. I set fractional display scaling in Gnome to 150%.
I'm trying to run Windows 10 as a guest OS. It runs fine, but VMware is honoring the host's screen scaling for the VM window, so I can either set scaling to 100% in Windows and let the OS scale the text up with blurry results or use scaling in Windows with VMware's autosize set to "stretch guest" in fullscreen mode and set the display resolution in Windows to the native resolution and have VMware scale it down and Wayland(?) scale it up.
I tried playing with fullscreen and autosize, but this is the best I found. How can I get VMware to use display scaling for its UI but not the guest display and delegate scaling to the guest?
